# How to loop through arrays of different length in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, loops, nested-loops

Let's say i have two relation arrays of a user's daily buy and sell.

how do i iterate through both of them using `.each` and still let the the longer array run independently once the shorter one is exhaused. Below i want to find the ratio of someone's daily buys and sells. But can't get the ratio because it's always 1 as i'm iterating through the longer array once for each item of the shorter array.

```
users = User.all
ratios = Hash.new

users.each do |user|

  if user.buys.count > 0 && user.sells.count > 0

    ratios[user.name] = Hash.new
    buy_array = []
    sell_array = []
    date = ""

    daily_buy = user.buys.group_by(&:created_at)
    daily_sell = user.sells.group_by(&:created_at)

    daily_buy.each do |buy|
      daily_sell.each do |sell|
        if buy[0].to_date == sell[0].to_date
          date = buy[0].to_date
          buy_array << buy[1]
          sell_array << sell[1]
        end
      end
    end
    ratio_hash[user.name][date] = (buy_array.length.round(2)/sell_array.length)
  end
end
```

Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand your question. Readers should not have to try to deduce questions from code, particularly from code that does not work. Think about how you could clearly state the question without presenting any code. Often an example helps. When you give an example, assign a variable each input object (e.g., `arr = [1,2,3]`) and show your desired output for that input. The reason for including the variables is so that readers can cut and paste and refer to them in comments and solutions without having to define them.

Comment: Also, avoid asking how a particular approach can be taken (e.g., "how do i iterate through both of them using `each`?"), so that you don't close off other, possibly better approaches. Just explain what you want to achieve. I suggest you edit your question to at least add an example. If you do that, leave what you have and add it at the end, indicating it's an edit (e.g. "Edit: ....").

Comment: An XY Problem ... http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem  

You currently have 3 nested loops (buys, sells, AND users). It'll take n^3 operations to deal with `n` users/buys/sells. Once any of the 3 inputs grows beyond a trivial number this will get painfully slow. You say you want "the ratio of daily buys & sells," but keeping only dates w/buy AND sell throws away lots of data, and otherwise ratio is 0 or undefined for whichever dates didn't have both buy/sell. Do you rather want trends for dates they bought OR sold? That's a different problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could concat both arrays and get rid of duplicated elements by doing:

```
(a_array + b_array).uniq.each do |num|
  # code goes here
end
```

[Uniq method API](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-uniq)

Comment: hey Roy, thanks for the tip. Though i've expended my question to include my actual problem, do take a look and tell me what you think.

Answer (score 0):

```
daily_buy = user.buys.group_by(&:created_at)
 daily_sell = user.sells.group_by(&:created_at

  buys_and_sells = daily_buy + daily_sell

  totals = buys_and_sells.inject({}) do |hsh, transaction|
    hsh['buys'] ||= 0;
    hsh['sells']  ||= 0;
    hsh['buys'] += 1 if transaction.is_a?(Buy)
    hsh['sells'] += 1 if transaction.is_a?(Sell)
    hsh
  end

  hsh['buys']/hsh['sells']
```

I think the above might do it...rather than collecting each thing in to separate arrays, concat them together, then run through each item in the combined array, increasing the count in the appropriate key of the hash returned by the inject.

Answer (score -1):

In this case you can't loop them with each use for loop
this code will give you a hint

```
ar = [1,2,3,4,5]
br = [1,2,3]

array_l = (ar.length > br.length) ? ar.length : br.length

for i in 0..array_l
    if ar[i] and br[i]
        puts ar[i].to_s + " " + br[i].to_s
    elsif ar[i]
      puts ar[i].to_s
    elsif br[i]
      puts br[i].to_s
    end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, i've expended my question to include my actual problem. not sure if this one will help but will think about this.